# Best way to return html strings?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working with a 3D software, which allows me to **pass HTML strings to the software**, and it will display said HTML strings in the 3D space.

I originally did something like the following:

```
function returnHTMLString(name){
  return `
  <style>
    .helloWorld{
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
  <div id = "helloWorld"> Hello world! My name is ${name}. </div>
  <script>
  ...
  </script>
`
}
```

But currently as my string has grown to become 300 lines long, it is becoming less and less manageable. Also VSCode does not do code checking on a string, so debugging and understanding my code has become very difficult.

I was thinking I could instead just have the string in a .html file, then I could somehow load it into my javascript file, pass the arguments into the loaded .html, then convert it into a string. Would this be possible?

I don't know if I can use react for this, since I want to return a string, not mount a HTML element onto the DOM. I also need to include a  tag in this html string, so I'm unsure if JSX will support it.

I'm happy with any solutions as long as they involve letting vscode recognize and color the code in the htmlString so I can debug better.

Comment: Have you considered using [`<template>` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template)?